# Running Apache SystemML

Tags: pyspark, systemml

I am trying to get Apache SystemML set up and running (on Ubuntu) in a standalone mode.
I am relying on the github documentation to set this up.
I would like to run this with pyspark and I am following the instructions from this beginner's [guide](http://apache.github.io/incubator-systemml/beginners-guide-python)

After successfully installing systemml and launching pyspark shell, I tried the following code from the tutorial:

```
import systemml as sml
import numpy as np
m1 = sml.matrix(np.ones((3,3)) + 2)
```

The import statements work fine, however I encounter the following error with the 3rd line:

```
ImportError: Unable to load systemML.jar into the current pyspark session.Hint: Provide 
the following argument to pyspark: --driver-class-path /usr/local...
```

As per the hint provided, I launched pyspark again appending the "--driver -class-path..." at the end. But I encountered the same error.

While googling for this, I found this error being highlighted in the Apache SystemML documentations. However, I wasn't really able to address the issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm that "/usr/local..." in your comment is path to systemml-*-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar and that file exists ?